# React JSX Dynamic Content : increment in top property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-state-management

i am absolutely begginner in react so please forgive me , i am stuck with Dynamic content creation , i cant make increment in top property , after render where i am using map and i am using top property , i dont know how to increase the num , i have tried in setstate but it does not work each time , it happens before render , and i only see pics at the last location

```
class People extends React.Component {
componentDidMount = () => {

 //$('#Dynamic').hide()

}

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    Info : []
  }

  var Ref = firebase.database().ref('Users');
  Ref.once('value' , (i) => {
    i.forEach((y)=>{
      var data = y.val()
      myArray[c] = data.Photo;
    //  alert(myArray[c]) ;
      c++ ; 

      this.setState({
        Info : myArray
              }) 

    })      
   }) 
  }

render () {
  n += 100;
    return (
        <div>
          <div id = 'Dynamic' >

    <div id = 'hi'> {  this.state.Info.map(i => 

    { return <img style = {{'top' : n  }} className = 'public'  src = {i}   /> }


      )} 



      </div>

     </div>

        </div>

    );

}



}

export default People
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. So, no multiple rendering while calling `setState` in a loop.